# What does Android 2.2.1 bring?

Tags: 2.2-froyo

Compared to 2.2, what does 2.2.1 bring that's new please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not aware of an official changelog anywhere, but you can look at the commit log on the git repository [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=shortlog;h=ec721fd1db4d895b342cfb83c651e0b78afac4dd). Anything between the `2.2_r1.3` tag and the `2.2.1_r1` tag was a change added in 2.2.1.

The summary: it's basically just bugfixes, hence why it's a smaller increment (as opposed to `2.2->2.3`, for example).

Note: If you're getting a 2.2.1 update from a carrier then they may have added other changes to their own software, so the above applies to the Android OS itself and not any additional components.

Answer (score 4):

Only for **Samsung Galaxy S** ( *but nevertheless very, very important* ):  **speed, speed, speed**.

My Galaxy is much, much quicker in handling all things - the lag that was present in previous versions up and including 2.2 is completely gone.

Update: maybe not only for Samsung Galaxy S ( come to think of it ) , but I have only the Samsung Galaxy S at my disposal.

Comment: How did you get this update?  Did you get it officially?  I'm just wondering because I have a Galaxy S Captivate that is still on 2.2.

Comment: @Chance It came down to i9000 (International) Galaxy S's through Kies back in February/early March (depending on your channel/network). I think just like the initial Froyo, it was released in Europe first.

Comment: @Chance: I got it using the regular KIES. One day I ( a few weeks back ), I opened KIES and it reported an update to 2.2.1 to be ready. I upgraded and as they say: never looked back. It really, really, really ..... really does make a big difference. My phone, which I was happy with before, mind you, is not just ideal. I can't compare with other devices, of course, but as it is now, my Samsung Galaxy S phone is a 'hell of a device'. I a living in Belgium, by the way.

Comment: yeah, I forgot that people outside the U.S. have been getting updates to their phone.  Thanks.